# Does Push activity on Journey Builder reach out to the contacts with Opted out status?

Tags: marketing-cloud, notification, push-notification, push

I'm on now process of testing Push message activity on Journey builder, and I'm not sure about how this push notification activity on Journey builder is processed on the Marketing cloud side.
It seems that all of the contacts(including Opted out one) has been processed on the Journey builder canvas regardless of its Optin status.
So here's where my curiosity occurs :

1. So could anyone explian how these contacts with Opted out status on push activity path is handeled on Marketing cloud side?
2. If it's being processed on the path, it seems that Marketing cloud try to reach out to contact, then would the super message be also be consumed even if push is not delivered ? Or would it be filtered automatically before it reach out to contact?
3. If the former one is the case on question number 2, will it be necessary to add decision split activity which is for filtering out all the Opted out one on Journey builder?

If anyone can share your insight, it would be a great help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- SFMC respects a contact's opt-in status and does not send push
  notifications to opted-out contacts.
- Despite their opt-in status, all contacts continue their journey in
  Journey Builder Canvas. Opted-out contacts go through a MobilePush activity, SFMC skips the push notification, but the contact proceeds in the
  journey.
- Super Messages are only consumed for successful sends. Skipped
  messages due to opt-out status do not consume Super Messages.

You may still add a decision split to filter out opted-out contacts for reporting.